# Consume WCF service from .NET Framework in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, .net-framework-version

WCF services are hosted on a local VM, written in .NET Framework. I need to consume it in a .NET Core application. When I try to connected it via **Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider**

[image] option, I get warning message like this

Moving forward ignoring this messages, I can see only endpoints implementing **async**.

Now if I try to invoke anyone of the async method, I get this error.

[image]

This is how I am instantiating it.

```
public class MotionSimulatorManager
{
public  MotionSimulatorManager()
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = "net.tcp://192.168.184.33:8458/MotionSimulator";

                var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);

                var binding = new NetTcpBinding
                {
                    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 59, 59),
                    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 59, 59),
                    MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                    Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None }
                };

                _motionSimulatorClient = new MotionSimulatorClient(binding, endpoint);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }




        public async Task<object> NameSake()
        {
            try
            {
                var res = _motionSimulatorClient.EstopAsync(); //error comes at this point.


                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("D://CollimatorType.txt", e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

How do I solve this ? Let me know if any other details is required.

Thanks in advance..

**EDIT:**

I introduced a proxy by adding .NET Framework project which consumes the WCF services and create a dll of that which I'm using in other .NET Core project but upon doing I'm getting this error while connecting to it.
[image]

Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the service configuration has the correct binding configuration,like this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="somebehavior"
         name="somename">
   <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="SomeBinding"
             name="http" 
             contract="somecontract" />
   <endpoint address="mex" 
             binding="mexHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration=""
             name="mex" 
             contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8700/service/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
   </host>
</service>
```

This bindingConfiguration was empty. It then takes the default wsHttpBinding which is something different then the one specified.